# I don't know how to align some elements to my menu

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar

I would like to align some elements on my website: the h2 "graphic design" and the p should be aligned vertically to the "home" element of the navbar and should be responsive. How do I do this? I've tried with mt/ml but they change in different screens. Thanks.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top mt-lg-4 mt-sm-0 mt-md-4 mt-xl-4">
            <a class="navbar-brand ml-4" href="index.html">
                <img src="img/logo.png" width=100% alt="" loading="lazy">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item mr-4">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link text-dark">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-4">
                        <div class="dropdown show">
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                progetti
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">

                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="graphicdesign.html">01. Graphic Design</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="videografica.html">02. Videografica</a>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-4">
                        <a href="chisono.html" class="nav-link text-dark ">chi sono?</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-1">
                        <a href="contattami.html" class="nav-link text-dark">contattami</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
                <img src="img/gd_graphicdesigngenerale.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md bg-white mt-5">
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="offset-2"></div>
                    <h2 class=" text-purple mt-5">01</h2>
                    <div class="offset-1"></div>
                    <h2 class=" text-purple ml-3 mt-5">graphic <br>design</h2>
                    <div class="d-flex offset-3 vertical-container align-items-center">
                        <p class="col-9 display-5 mt-5 ml-3 mb-5">Qui puoi trovare una selezione dei miei progetti di graphic design. La monografia di Armin Hofmann, grafico pioniero dello Swiss Design, e i cinque poster di tipografia espressiva realizzati per gli aforismi di Ludwig Wittgenstein. Tutti questi lavori sono stati eseguiti all'Accademia di Belle Arti di Palermo.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offset-4">

                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The HTML you have posted is broken, there are multiple `</div>` missing, your img tag has no fixed size, and the image in question is not visible for any reader.

For personalized help, I'd recomment you to fix your HTML code first, and replace the img link with an https://via.placeholder.com/100x75 of the corresponding size of your logo.

Comment: could you help me describing this problem with the expected output image type?